# Running python script in Python IDLE from VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line

If I run Python script in VS Code, I would like new window to open and script should run in it. The same way it works if you just open the file using Python from file explorer. As far as I know, VS Code provides only running the script in VS code terminal.

As an example, atom-python-run extension for Atom has the same behaviour. Is there any way to achieve this in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to run Python REPL in another window in Visual Studio Code.

You can run the program in external window. To do this, open "Run and Debug" section from left panel and then click `create a launch.json file`:

[image: run and debug panel]

In opened file change `console` property value to `externalTerminal`:

```json
"console": "externalTerminal"
```

Save the file. After that programs from folder which contain `.vscode/launch.json` file will run in external terminal.